# layout architecture :- make textview as toolbar with animation

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design

currently i have achieved following stuff as shown in image 
 so right now  when i scroll 1st viewpager goes, textview and tablayout becomes sticky for this i am using https://github.com/noties/Scrollable and now i want when viewpager goes and textview and tablayout is sticky that time make that textview to be invisible/gone and toolbar should get that title with some kind of animation like we get by using CollapsingToolbarLayout ..

```
my xml :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ru.noties.scrollable.ScrollableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:CustomTabLayout="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollable_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:scrollable_closeUpAnimationMillis="250"
    app:scrollable_closeUpAnimatorInterpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    app:scrollable_considerIdleMillis="125"
    app:scrollable_defaultCloseUp="true"
    app:scrollable_friction="5"
    app:scrollable_maxScroll="150dp"
    app:scrollable_scrollerFlywheel="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/header_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Ui.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/ti"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textColor="@color/red"
                    android:textSize="30dp" />

                <Ui.CustomTabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/ti"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    CustomTabLayout:fonts="@string/font_Oswald"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/red" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</ru.noties.scrollable.ScrollableLayout>
```

[image]